# In a Windows Python script, can you `os.rename` on a directory that contains the script itself?

Tags: python, windows

On Windows, with a file structure like this:

```
project/
--- script.py
```

If `script.py` contains a line `os.rename(folder, new_folder)` where `folder` is the path to the `project/` folder, then opening a command prompt and navigating to the `project/` and running `python script.py` raises a `PermissionError`.

In File Explorer, I also cannot rename `project/`, then I close the command prompt, and now in File Explorer I am able to rename `project/`. I assume the command prompt being open to `project/` then is also responsible for the Python script's failure.

Is there a way for a Python script to rename a folder that contains the script itself?

Comment: I just tried on Linux and I can indeed rename the folder that contains the renaming script. Which is in the end logical as whenever a python script is executed it is parsed and loaded into the RAM, so no longer dependent on the location of the script on the file system.

Comment: If any process has either the "project" directory open or any file or directory within it, then a standard rename in Windows will fail. The native NT API in Windows 10 supports a [POSIX rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_rename_information) mode that can succeed here, but it's not documented in the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Windows if you execute the script from a directory different from the directory the script is in/you want to rename. Considering the error you receive when running from `C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project python script.py` (where the script.py script changes the parent directory name from project to newProject):

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\project' -> 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\newProject'
```

However running the same script from a different directory:
`C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ python project\script.py`:

Will work and change the directory name.

Comment: A caveat is that it depends on the script. If the script, or any other process, has any files open in the subtree of the parent directory, then a normal rename will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are right in that the active, or "current", directory of the command parser counts as "open", so it cannot be renamed.

Does your script address "container directory" or "current directory"? In either case, if simply running it "from the outside" doesn't work, you could try the "start" command, but perhaps slightly different:
start /b /d project python script.py
... or without the directory switch ...
start /b python project\script.py

The /b switch runs the command without opening a new command shell, so I guess some interaction interfaces (console i/o, shell variables) may fail.